# Bug (?) coord_flip() doesn't work properly with coord_cartesian() and geom_errorbar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've this code for generating the plot:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Male", "Female"),y = c(5, 6), error = c(1, 10))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x, y=y, ymax=y+error, ymin=y-error))+
geom_errorbar(width=.15)+
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,10))+ 
geom_point(shape=22, size=3, fill="red")+
coord_flip()+
theme_bw(20)
```

[image]
As reported, `coord_cartesian()`  seems dosen't work properly with `coord_flip()`. In fact commenting:

```
#coord_flip()+
```

The following is generated:

[image]

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Use `+ ylim(...)` instead of `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = ...)`? Otherwise use `ggstance::geom_errorbarh` instead of `coord_flip()`.

Comment: Or supply `ylim` to `coord_flip()` instead, since the help says: _"`...`:
Other arguments passed onto `coord_cartesian`"_.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Axeman said in his/her comment, if you include `coord_flip(ylim=c(0,10)` in your ggplot object, you will will get the second plot in your question with the coordinates flipped. In fact, you don't even need `coord_cartesian`--the following code...

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x, y=y, ymax=y+error, ymin=y-error))+
geom_errorbar(width=.15)+
geom_point(shape=22, size=3, fill="red")+
coord_flip(ylim = c(0,10))+
theme_bw(20)
```

... produces this plot:

[image]